# Maxwell stress tensor for electric field

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

If we need to calculate the time-averaged Maxwell stress tensor for an arbitrary field like

$$
\vec{E}=E_{0x}e^{ikz-iwt}\hat{i} + E_{0y}e^{ikz-iwt}\hat{j}+E_{0z}e^{ikz-iwt}\hat{k}
$$

I know we should omit the $e^{-iwt}$ term and multiply by $\frac{1}{2}$ to get the time average, but since the Maxwell stress tensor should be real, what would happen to the $e^{ikz}$ terms? Because they do not get canceled in the stress tensor's formulas like:

$$
T_{xy} = \epsilon_{0}(E_xE_y)+\frac{1}{\mu_0}(B_xB_y)
$$

and other terms. Should the multiplication be conjugated like $E_xE^*_y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Electric and Magnetic fields in Classical Electromagnetism are **not** complex fields, they are real.

However, when the fields vary sinusoidally, we need to keep track of the amplitude and the phase, and a complex number is an easy way to do this. Thus, we use complex numbers to denote electromagnetic waves because they greatly simplify most calculations, with the understanding that we are actually interested in the real part, which we extract at the end. However, this only works as long as the operations that we perform on the fields are linear, since these keep the imaginary and real parts separate during calculations.

However, if you perform a non-linear operation (such as squaring the field, for example) the real and imaginary parts would mix, and so using the complex representation breaks down when we try to calculate the Poynting vector using the "usual" definition, or more generally, the Electromagnetic Stress-Energy Tensor. In these cases, you should in fact either be using the real part of the complex field you mentioned above, or a different definition for the quantities.

Comment: Thanks! I think this applies to the ikz part, is the case I said about time-averaging true? That would deal with the -iwt term.

Comment: Well, if you took the real part, then the complex exponential (in time) would just become $-\sin(\omega t)$, which, in your definition of $T_{xy}$ would give you a $\sin^2(\omega t)$. The time average of $\sin^2(\omega t)$ is $1/2$, so yes, that would work as well. (I balk at the idea of "omitting" the  complex exponential and replacing it with $1/2$, this method makes it clear *why* we do that.)